# Variance Inflation Factor to Address Spatial Grouping with Binary Dependent Variable

Tags: regression, clustering, spatial

I want to obtain reliable standard errors of the estimated coefficients from a regression of y on x.  The observation for each individual consisted of a value of the y variable, which is binary, and a location. The latter was assigned to one of 8 geographical areas, the x values being estimated averages (from secondary data) over each of the areas.  Thus the data is grouped, with x constant within each of the groups.  The size of the groups varies considerably.

Because of the grouping I expect that I need to apply a variance inflation factor to the OLS standard errors.  Angrist & Pischke in [Mostly Harmless Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691120358) p 311 give this formula:

$$\frac{V(\hat\beta_1)}{V_c(\hat\beta_1)} = 1+[\frac{V(n_g)}{\overline{n}} +\overline{n}-1]\rho_x\rho_e$$

Here $V(\hat\beta_1)$ is the true variance, $V_c(\hat\beta_1)$ the conventional OLS variance, $n_g$ the size of the $g$'th group, $\overline{n}$ the mean group size, $\rho_x$ the intraclass correlation of x (1 in my case) and $\rho_e$ the intraclass correlation of the error term.  However, I haven't been able to find out whether this formula is valid with a binary dependent variable.

Is there a formula for a variance inflation factor to address grouping in a regression with a small number of groups and a binary dependent variable?